# calculate number of calls made to WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a service contract with 5 different operation contract and hosted in IIS.

Now suppose I want to charge customer (client) based on number of calls made to our WCF service (hitting different-different operation contract  ).

How is it possible to do so in WCF, what settings we need to do in WCF service side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF offers **extensibility points**; wherein WCF extension facilitates to plug in any custom code at different places in WCF Pipeline.

For your need, you can use the `MessageInspector` to inspect the message and increment a counter for the method call. *MessageInspector allows to intercept and examines the messages coming in or going out of the service layer infrastructure*. Message inspector can be applied on both the client and Server side.

1.In this specific scenario, you need to use the Server-side inspector by implementing `IDispatchMessageInspector`

```
public class MessageCounterMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        // Increment Counter in thread safe way
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {        
    }
}
```

2. Then implement the `IServiceBehavior` interface.

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
   public class CounterBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
   {
   public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   {
   }

   public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.Count; i++)
       {
           ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers[i] as ChannelDispatcher;
           if (channelDispatcher != null)
           {
               foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
               {
                   MessageCounterMessageInspector inspector = new MessageCounterMessageInspector ();
                   endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
               }
           }
       }
   }

   public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
   {
   }
   }
   ```
3. Apply the attribute in step2 to your service class.

   ```
   [CounterBehavior]
   public class YourService : IYourService
   {

   }
   ```

**Note : For Counter, you may use the Static variable to keep a track of count of method, just ensure that the increment in thread safe.**

Answer (score 0):

You can either call some standard method from each of the service implementation methods (perhaps using [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to save yourself some typing)

or you can inject "accounting" methods by using [WCF custom behaviors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730137(v=vs.100).aspx)